Electron app cant keep entry in Privacy & Security > Screen & System Audio Recording
Some very few OSX users of my Electron app cant seem to be able to keep the app entry in the list of Privacy & Security > Screen & System Audio Recording allowed apps.
After they manually add the App, then alt-tab back to it to find that the entry dissapears as soon as they click on the function that triggers the screen capture functionality,
The library in question is "electron-color-picker".
its a sort of color picker, like the Eye dropper tool from Adobe PS,
It needs to capture the screen to be able to allow the user to select the pixel they want to color check.
It happens on some select computers..
And are all under the SAME LATEST version of OSX since its company policy to stay up to date.
I did update the electron frame work,
I did update the color-picker library,
Still cant seem to troubleshoot it very well since its not happening for me .
